WSGI Application error when attempting to register
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column user.is_active does not exist LINE 1: ... user_password, "user".is_admin AS user_is_admin, "user".is_... ^ [SQL: SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".username AS user_username, "user".email AS user_email, "user".password AS user_password, "user".is_admin AS user_is_admin, "user".is_active AS user_is_active, "user".created_at AS user_created_at, "user".last_login AS user_last_login FROM "user" WHERE "user".username = %(username_1)s LIMIT %(param_1)s] [parameters: {'username_1': 'testuser', 'param_1': 1}] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
Traceback (most recent call last)


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1967, in _exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 941, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1498, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/main.py", line 92, in register
if form.validate_on_submit():
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 86, in validate_on_submit
return self.is_submitted() and self.validate(extra_validators=extra_validators)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 329, in validate
return super().validate(extra)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 146, in validate
if not field.validate(self, extra):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 246, in validate
stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 266, in _run_validation_chain
validator(form, self)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/forms.py", line 21, in validate_username
user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2728, in first
return self.limit(1)._iter().first()  # type: ignore
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2827, in _iter
result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2362, in execute
return self._execute_internal(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2247, in _execute_internal
result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
result = conn.execute(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1418, in execute
return meth(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 515, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1640, in _execute_clauseelement
ret = self._execute_context(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1846, in _execute_context
return self._exec_single_context(



File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1986, in _exec_single_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
^


File "/home/runner/MediaManagerApp/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2355, in _handle_dbapi_exception


